# JAWS doesn't read dynamic content. IE11

Tags: javascript, accessibility, internet-explorer-11, jaws-screen-reader, aria-live

I have a search form. When user submits form, ajax request is sent to the server. When the response comes, I update found items count value, but JAWS reads previous items count value.
To get JAWS read new content I use aria attributes and role="status". But JAWS still doesn't work as expected.

What I've tried:
[Getting screen reader to read new content added with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670570/getting-screen-reader-to-read-new-content-added-with-javascript),
[aria-live and JAWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908701/aria-live-and-jaws), [ARIA Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) and etc.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<form class="search-form">
     <label class="keyword-search-input-label" for="keyword-search-input">
          <span class="hide">Search</span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="keyword-search-input" name="keyword"/>
     </label>

     <button id="clear-field-button" type="reset">
          <span class="hide">Clear Search Field</span>
     </button>
     <button id="search-button" type="submit" aria-describedby="number-found-items">
          <span class="symbol-label">Search</span>
     </button>
</form>
<div id="number-found-items" role="status" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" aria-relevant="all">
      <span id="number-found">0</span>
      items found
</div>
```

JS

```
function updateNumberFound(value) {
    $numberFound.text(value || 0);
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17mkL2n5/)
To reproduce the problem try to focus on search input, type some text and press search button, while JAWS is on.

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @unobf, I've added jsfiddle. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to use a role="log" region that is inserted into the document when it loads and is off screen. Then to append the text that you want announced to that region when updates occur.

I have modified your fiddle to include the [a11yfy library's](https://github.com/dylanb/a11yfy) code which does this: https://jsfiddle.net/17mkL2n5/1/embedded/result/

```
jQuery.a11yfy.assertiveAnnounce(value + ' items found');
```

I have tested this on OS X with VO, Windows with NVDA and Windows IE 11 with JAWS 14 and they all work correctly.

Comment: I've checked the solution, that you provided, but, unfortunately, JAWS's behavior is still the same)

Comment: what version of JAWS and what browser?

Comment: JAWS 15.0.4203 and IE11, Chrome 41

Comment: I hope you are not expecting it to work in Chrome - it works fine for me in IE11 with JAWS 14

Comment: I hope, that the solution will be found and it will work for at least in IE11 with JAWS 15.

Comment: I tested it with JAWS 15 and IE11 and it works there too

Comment: Also tested in IE 11 with JAWS 16

Comment: I've figured out, why it doesn't work in my environment. It was very not obvious)

There is a **list of items** in my project, which is updated, when the response from the server comes. Because of this list JAWS doesn't read **found items count value**. It seems, that the list update interrupts JAWS announcement.

Is there any way to tell JAWS to not react on **items list** changes?

Comment: can you jsfiddle a more complete example?